# Building packages with Rcpp, Attributes not handled correctly

Tags: r, rstudio, rcpp

I've been playing around with setting up an R package which aims to make use of Rcpp in RStudio, but I'm struggling to get things to work properly with Rcpp Attributes.

My understanding of how this works is fairly tenuous, but my understanding is as follows:

1. In the source C++ files, you can add Rcpp Attributes, for example the tag `// [[Rcpp::export]]` marks a C++ function for exporting, making it available for R.
2. When you do Build the package, `Rcpp` then generates the appropriate C++ code in the file `RcppExports.cpp`, and wrapper functions in the R source file `RcppExports.R`.

This doesn't seem to be working properly (as I expect) when I build my package. Roxygen isn't playing nicely with this when generating the NAMESPACE file (so i've disabled that). The tag `// [[Rcpp::export]]` seems to just mark the function for exporting to R, rather than also marking a function for being exported to the package Namespace.

More importantly, the Rcpp Attribute tag `// [[Rcpp::depends()]]` isn't being handled correctly. If I copy the code [here](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-bigmemory-with-rcpp/) into a new source file, and rebuild my package, `gcc` throws errors on the `RcppExports.cpp` file saying that the `BigMatrix` identifier is undeclared indicating that the attribute tage `// [[Rcpp::depends(bigmemory)]]` isn't being handled correctly.

Since multiple things aren't working as I would expect, What am I missing in my understanding of Rcpp Attribute tags?

Comment: You could just write your function interface by hand, rather than relying on Rcpp Attributes and its `compileAttributes()` helper.  After all, you do have a special case here (== need for special header).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue with the `RcppExports.cpp` file that is generated. At the moment, there is no way to teach it to include header files from somewhere else, so it just does not include `bigmemory/MatrixAccessor.hpp`.

A workaround is to do this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <bigmemory/MatrixAccessor.hpp>

Rcpp::NumericVector BigColSums(Rcpp::XPtr<BigMatrix> pBigMat) {

    // Create the matrix accessor so we can get at the elements of the matrix.
    MatrixAccessor<double> ma(*pBigMat);

    // Create the vector we'll store the column sums in.
    Rcpp::NumericVector colSums(pBigMat->ncol());
    for (size_t i=0; i < pBigMat->ncol(); ++i)
        colSums[i] = std::accumulate(ma[i], ma[i]+pBigMat->nrow(), 0.0);
    return colSums;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector BigColSums( SEXP pBigMat ){
    return  BigColSums( Rcpp::XPtr<BigMatrix>( pBigMat) ) ;   
}
```

So that you capture the type in your `.cpp` file and `RcppExports.cpp` only has to know about `SEXP`.

Answer (score 4):

`// [[Rcpp::export]]` doesn't export functions to the package `NAMESPACE`, it just says "we should make this function available to R" -- it's still up to you on how you want to manage this function in your namespace.

Roxygen works to parse roxygen tags from source file comments; you'll have to include an `//' @export` tag in your `.cpp` source files, as partially described in [3.4 of the attributes vignette](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf).

For your second problem, you still need to make sure `bigmemory` is in your `Depends:` and `LinkingTo:` sections of your `DESCRIPTION` file. I suppose one might prefer for `// [[Rcpp::depends]]` to automatically modify the package `DESCRIPTION` file, but it's easy enough to do yourself.

There was also a similar discussion [here](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/questions/1495-rcpp-and-roxygen) on the RStudio help boards.

Comment: Thanks, that's solved my problem with the `NAMESPACE` file, and explained some of my gaps in Roxygen knowledge! Adding `@useDynLib bigmemory` doesn't fix the issue however. I've also got `bigmemory` listed as both a dependency and a link in the `DESCRIPTION` file.